# Highlight div box on hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Say I have a div with the following attributes:

```
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 67px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

How would I make it so that if someone hovers their mouse over this area, it changes the background to a slightly darker colour and makes it a clickable area?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**CSS Only:**

```
.box:hover{
background: blue; /* make this whatever you want */
}
```

To make it a 'clickable' area, you're going to want to put a `<a></a>` tag inside the div, and you may want to use jQuery to set the `href` attribute.

**jQuery Solution**

```
$('.box').hover(function(){
$(this).css("background", "blue");
$(this).find("a").attr("href", "www.google.com");
});
```

**A third solution:**
You could change the cursor, and also give it a click event using jQuery:

```
$('.box').click(function(){
// do stuff
});
```

Use the above along with the following CSS:

```
.box{
background: blue;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: What if I wanted to have a border when you hover over the div of 5px all around without screwing up the placement of the things around it?

Comment: @ShadyPotato If you add a border, it's going to add to the elements width. You're going to need to account for that.

Comment: So say I have the 300px x 67px div, and there are the same divs above and below this div. How would I make it so that if you hovered over the div, it would highlight it as you suggested, but made it highlight 5px larger than the div size?

Comment: @ShadyPotato I would just change the width and height attributes using jQuery, just realize that you're going to have to adjust accordingly so the rest of the elements on the page don't go all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

```
.box:hover {
    background: #999;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

When you hover the background changes to the color you want and cursor becomes pointer. You can trigger an event with jQuery like so:

```
$('.box').click(customFunction);
```

Answer (score 1):

Linking a div has worked for me simply by wrapping it in an **a** tag. Here is an example below with Bootstrap classes:

```
<a href="#">
<div class="col-md-4">

<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send headericon"></span>

<p class="headerlabel">SEND</p>
<p class="headerdescription">Send candidate survey</p>    

</div> 
</a>
```

To change your div colour on hover add:

```
div:hover {
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

to your CSS :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CSS only:

```
.box:hover{
  background: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Or with Javascript (I'm using jQuery in this example)

```
;(function($){
  $('.box').bind('hover', function(e) {
    $(this).css('background', 'blue');
  });
})(jQuery);
```